# как использовать в одном коде StringReplace, MidStr, Trim

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

У меня есть edith, я ввожу там номер. Я сделал такой код, но когда я его вхожу, появляется ошибка, я понимаю, что это из-за StringReplache потому что я его 
 использую два раза, как сделать все в одном коде, чтобы удалить все пробелы и поменять запятую на точку

```
procedure TForm26.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  t1: string;
begin
  t1 := StringReplace(edt2.Text, ',', '.', [rfReplaceAll]);
  t1 := Trim(edt2.Text);
  t1 := StringReplace(t1, ' ', '', [rfReplaceAll]);

  qry1.SQL.Clear;
  qry1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO Facial(summa) VALUES('+#39+t1+#39+')');
  qry1.ExecSQL;
end;
```

когда я ввожу число с запятой, я получаю сообщение об ошибке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А число, которое вы вводите, с точкой или с запятой? Оба варианта не работают? А если просто число, без разделителя, тоже не работает? Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: число ввожу с запятой, пробелы с правой и левой стороны и между цифрами работает

Comment: А число, которое вы вводите, с точкой или с запятой? Оба варианта попробуйте, оба не работают? А если просто число, без разделителя, тоже не работает?

Comment: число ввожу с запитой оно и не работает, в коде же написано что запятая надо поменять на точки. целое число и с точкой работает

Comment: Базы данных не очень любят динамический SQL, за день можно заставить такими запросами сервер СУБД тормозить. Лучше делать параметрические выборки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код, надо подправить, т.к. вы затираете результаты первого `StringReplace`, и лучше вот так (правка, с учетом замечания @Kromster):

```
t1 := Trim(edt2.Text);
t1 := StringReplace(t1, ',', DecimalSeparator, [rfReplaceAll]);
t1 := StringReplace(t1, '.', DecimalSeparator, [rfReplaceAll]);
t1 := StringReplace(t1, ' ', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Comment: Alexander Chernin Ваш ответ не работает

Comment: @Kromster вы правы, конечно надо менять на DecimalSeparator